# Twitter API v 1.1 code in PHP

Tags: php, twitter, tweets

I am using twitter API v1.1 to get tweets in my web application the code for getting tweets is as 
`$name = 'zkalvi';
        $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json/".$name;
        $tweets = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($tweets as $tweet) {
            echo '<li>'.$tweet->text.'</li>';

        }
        echo '</ul>';`
and `$name = 'zkalvi';
        $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json/".$name;
        $tweets = simplexml_load_file($url);
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($tweets as $tweet) {
            echo '<li>'.$tweet->text.'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';`
both of these codes are not showing the tweets.
Please help me why the tweets are not showing and how could I show the tweets?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, the way you are calling is wrong, your url should be like this
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=zkalvi.

By this url you will get following output

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

This is because , in twitter 1.1 version, most of thing needs authentication. So better you use twitter server side  library for getting results.

Here is link for twitteroauth library for php
[twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)

Comment: Thanks Jay Hardia but i could not found the library in twitter documentation. could you please provide some help?